# Blend 2 bitmaps

Tags: winapi, gdi+

I have 2 buffers pointing to RGB32 images of different sizes, so my idea is to scale one buffer to match the other one and alphablend these images.

Currently I am able to mix StretchBlt (for scaling performance) and GDI+ drawimage function with a colormatrix for alphablending. This seem to be a bit slow and also it has issues with buffer being used by a different component that uses DirectX. For buffer issue I tried to copy the rows in reverse order and it works except in the DirectX related component.

```
Bitmap bmp1(width, height, 4bytesperpixel, RGB32, bufferpointer1);
Bitmap blend(width, height, 4bytesperpixel);
Graphics g(&newbmp)

using GDI function
Bitmap bmp2(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, 4bytesperpixel, RGB32, bufferpointer2)
HDC memdc = g.GetHDC();

////  scaling the bufferpointer2 to actual width & height
StretchDIBits(memdc, x,y, width, height, 0, 0,scaleWidth, scaleHeight, bufferpointer2,..)
g.ReleaseDC(memdc); // so that content is copied to the bitmap

//// Then alphablending bmp1 on top of the scaled imaged bmp2
//// Using lockbits to copy the bitmap bytes and unlocking it.
```

So I would need to replace the GDI+ functions and use Win32 function like AlphaBlend for this. I tried something like this and it shows a black screen

```
    BITMAPINFO bminfo1 = {};
    bminfo1.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof( BITMAPINFO );
    bminfo1.bmiHeader.biWidth = w;
    bminfo1.bmiHeader.biHeight = h;
    bminfo1.bmiHeader.biBitCount = m_nBytesPerPixel * 8;
    bminfo1.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bminfo1.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;

    BITMAPINFO bminfo2 = {};
    bminfo2.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof( BITMAPINFO );
    bminfo2.bmiHeader.biWidth = sW;
    bminfo2.bmiHeader.biHeight = sH;
    bminfo2.bmiHeader.biBitCount = m_nBytesPerPixel * 8;
    bminfo2.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bminfo2.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;

    char* pBytes1, *pBytes2;

    HDC hmemdc1 = CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(0));
    HDC hmemdc2 = CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(0));

    HBITMAP hBitmap1 = CreateDIBSection(hmemdc1, &bminfo1, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**) &pBytes1, NULL, 0);
    SetDIBits(hmemdc1, hBitmap1, 0, bminfo1.bmiHeader.bih, pBuffer[0], &bminfo1, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    HBITMAP hBitmap2 = CreateDIBSection(hmemdc2, &bminfo2, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**) &pBytes2, NULL, 0);
    SelectObject(hmemdc2,hBitmap2);
    StretchDIBits(hmemdc2, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0,
        sW, sH, pBuffer[1], &bminfo2, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY );

    BLENDFUNCTION bStruct; 
    bStruct.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bStruct.BlendFlags = 0;
    bStruct.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    bStruct.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    SelectObject(hmemdc1,hBitmap1);
    SelectObject(hmemdc2,hBitmap2);

    //blend bmp2 on bmp1
    BOOL res = AlphaBlend(hmemdc1, 0, 0, w, h, hmemdc2, 0, 0, w, h, bStruct);

    //for testing output
    SelectObject(hmemdc1,hBitmap1);
    BitBlt(GetDC(0),0,0,width,height,hmemdc1,100,100,SRCCOPY);


    //copy the bitmap buffer
    memcpy(out, pBytes1, (w * m_nBytesPerPixel) * h);
```

I am not sure if it is possible to use AlphaBlend function to mix bitmaps per-pixel based from 2 memory DCs. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show real code. At the moment there's no way to tell if you've just forgotten something simple (e.g. you don't show that you select `hBitmap1` into `hmemdc1`) or if there's more to it.

Comment: AlphaBlend will definitely work on two in-memory bitmaps. I would check the result from StretchDIBits, and also that you've setup the blendfunction param correctly

Comment: @JonathanPotter I've edited to add complete code. gordy, StretchDIBits and Bitblt functions used works as expected

Comment: `SetDIBits` is for use with a DDB, but `hBitmap1` is a DIB - not sure whether that would work or not. You could try `SetDIBitsToDevice` instead. And if you're using `AC_SRC_ALPHA` you're telling GDI that the source bitmap has a (pre-multipled) alpha channel. Does it? What's the value of `m_nBytesPerPixel` ?

Comment: Other problems include `BitBlt(GetDC(0), ...` which is an obvious resource leak.

Comment: @JonathanPotter SetDIBits works fine and actually I could see the output in BitBlt for both hmemdc1 and hmemdc2 separately(without AlphaBlend fn executed). And I've tried with and without pre-multiplying pBytes[1] after SetDIBits(), not sure if I have to do this for pBytes[2] as well. When I add pre-multiply code, I see the hmemdc1 output with a mask. Only when AlphaBlend funtion is called, it just draws the black screen. Also I would like to know if AlphaBlend fn actually blends 2 images based on source per-pixel, i.e something like overlay effect with transparency.

Comment: AlphaBlend will do per pixel alpha but assumes the source is premultiplied - check the docs on [BLENDFUNCTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
bminfo1.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof( BITMAPINFO );
```

It should be **`sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)`** otherwise it ruins everything. Also you can't use `GetDC(0)` for any proper painting. Use instead:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
...
ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
```

or use `HDC` from `BeginPaint`. Since you are using GDI+ then you must have `HBITMAP` handles from `bmp->GetHBITMAP()`, there is no reason to convert to memory and back to `HBITMAP`

For `AlphaBlend` set `SourceConstantAlpha = 128;` in case alpha channel is not set.

```
void blend(HDC hdc, RECT rc, HBITMAP hbitmap1, HBITMAP hbitmap2)
{
    HDC memdc1 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HDC memdc2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

    BITMAP bmp1, bmp2;
    GetObject(hbitmap1, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp1);
    GetObject(hbitmap2, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp2);

    SelectObject(memdc1, hbitmap1);
    SelectObject(memdc2, hbitmap2);

    BLENDFUNCTION blend = { 0 };
    blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 128;

    SetStretchBltMode(hdc, COLORONCOLOR);
    AlphaBlend(memdc2, 0, 0, bmp2.bmWidth, bmp2.bmHeight, memdc1, 0, 0, bmp1.bmWidth, bmp1.bmHeight, blend);
    StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, memdc2, 0, 0, bmp2.bmWidth, bmp2.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

    //or create another memdc to get dibs

    DeleteDC(memdc1);
    DeleteDC(memdc2);
}
```

In case you want to get dibs, then don't draw on `hdc`, instead create a third `memdc` and another `HBITMAP`, then use `GetDIBits`

```
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom);
SelectObject(memdc, hbmp);
SetStretchBltMode(memdc, COLORONCOLOR);
StretchBlt(memdc, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, 
    memdc2, 0, 0, bmp2.bmWidth, bmp2.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

int w = rc.right;
int h = rc.bottom;
BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) };
bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = w;
bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = h;
bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;

DWORD size = w * 4 * h;
char *dib = new char[size];
GetDIBits(hdc, hbmp, 0, h, dib, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmpInfoHeader, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
...
DeleteDC(memdc);
DeleteObject(hbitmap);
delete[]dib;
```

---

Edit

Method 2: This method should be faster because it uses one `StretchBlt` and one `AlphaBlend`. This way you can use pre-computed alphas, although it's not necessary.

Use the other method with 2 `AlphaBlend` only if you want to blend both images with background.

```
void modify_bits(HDC hdc, HBITMAP hbitmap) 
{   //expecting 32-bit bitmap
    BITMAP bm = { 0 };
    GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
    int w = bm.bmWidth;
    int h = bm.bmHeight;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),
        w, h, 1, 32, BI_RGB, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    BYTE* bits = new BYTE[w * h * 4];
    if (GetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap, 0, h, bits, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmpInfoHeader, DIB_RGB_COLORS)) {
        BYTE* p = bits;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                p[3] = 128;
                p[0] = p[0] * p[3] / 255;
                p[1] = p[1] * p[3] / 255;
                p[2] = p[2] * p[3] / 255;
                p += 4;
            }
        }
        SetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap, 0, h, bits, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmpInfoHeader, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    }
    delete[] bits;
}

void blend2(HDC hdc, RECT rc, HBITMAP hbitmap1, HBITMAP hbitmap2)
{
    int w = rc.right;
    int h = rc.bottom;

    modify_bits(hdc, hbitmap2);

    HDC memdc1 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HDC memdc2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

    BITMAP bmp1, bmp2;
    GetObject(hbitmap1, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp1);
    GetObject(hbitmap2, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp2);
    int w1 = bmp1.bmWidth;
    int h1 = bmp1.bmHeight;
    int w2 = bmp2.bmWidth;
    int h2 = bmp2.bmHeight;

    SelectObject(memdc1, hbitmap1);
    SelectObject(memdc2, hbitmap2);

    BLENDFUNCTION blend = { 0 };
    blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    blend.BlendFlags = 0;
    blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    SetStretchBltMode(hdc, COLORONCOLOR);

    //draw first image normally:
    StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, memdc1, 0, 0, w1, h1, SRCCOPY);

    //AlphaBlend the second image:
    AlphaBlend(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, memdc2, 0, 0, w2, h2, blend);

    DeleteDC(memdc1);
    DeleteDC(memdc2);
}
```

Comment: If I set only SourceConstantAlpha to 128, it works fine. But when I pre-multiply the pixels and set blendop to AC_SRC_OVER, then it just displays black screen. I am not sure if pixel format is the problem.

Comment: I don't see any code relevant to pre-multiplying the pixels, so I can't comment.

Comment: for (int y=0; y<bminfo1.bmiHeader.biHeight; ++y)
  {
   BYTE *pPixel= (BYTE *) ppvBits1 + bminfo1.bmiHeader.biWidth * 4 * y;
   for (int x=0; x<bminfo1.bmiHeader.biWidth ; ++x)
   {
    pPixel[0]= pPixel[0]*pPixel[3]/255;
    pPixel[1]= pPixel[1]*pPixel[3]/255;
    pPixel[2]= pPixel[2]*pPixel[3]/255;
    pPixel+= 4;
   }
  }
This is the code, I call it after SetDIBits of first bitmap.

Comment: Actually, I think my explanation was off a bit. See updated answer, method2. It should work with pre-computed alpha channel. Just make sure the alpha channel is set to non-zero value (`pPixel[3]`)

Comment: I already tried setting 128 to pixel3 but it still it has no effect, meaning it still shows the black screen when alphablend was called. I didn't know AlphaBlend can actually scale it, I'll try that.